# SQL query to find all the states where store is not open?

Tags: sql, join, notin

I have table A Stores which have store information. Table B have all states information. I need to join table A to B to get all the states where store is open. Now I need to find all the states where store is in not open.

Table A:

| Stores | StateCode |
| --- | --- |
| Store A | MP |
| Store B | UP |
| Store B | MP |
| Store C | JK |

Table B:

| StateCode | StateName |
| --- | --- |
| MP | Madhya Pradesh |
| UP | Uttar Pradesh |
| JK | Jammu Kashmir |

Output table:

| Stores | StateCode | StateName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store A | UP | Uttar Pradesh |
| Store A | JK | Jammu Kashmir |
| Store B | JK | Jammu Kashmir |
| Store C | UP | Uttar Pradesh |
| Store C | MP | Madhya Pradesh |

I have tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA
  ON tableA.<stateCode> = tableB.<stateCode>
WHERE tableA.<stateCode> IS NULL
```

Comment: Try A LEFT JOIN B instead.

Answer (score 1):

If You Use Microsoft SQL Server , Try This Query

```
SELECT Distinct
       A.Stores,
       B.StateCode,
       B.StateName
FROM TableA as A INNER JOIN TableB as B
ON B.StateCode Not IN (SELECT Statecode FROM TableA WHERE Stores = A.Stores)
```

Answer (score 0):

use sample :

```
SELECT
  `A`.`Stores`,
  `B`.`StateCode`,
  `B`.`StateName`
FROM
  `A`
  INNER JOIN `B` ON `B`.`StateCode` Not IN (
    SELECT
      `a1`.`Statecode`
    FROM
      `A` As `a1`
    WHERE
      `a1`.`Stores` = `A`.`Stores`
  )
GROUP By
  `A`.`Stores`,
  `B`.`StateCode`,
  `B`.`StateName`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a cross join between tableB and the distinct stores' values from tableA to get all possible combinations of (stores, states), then do a left join as the following:

```
select DA.Stores, B.StateCode, B.StateName
from tableB B cross join 
(
  select distinct Stores from tableA
) DA
left join tableA TA
on TA.Stores = DA.Stores and 
   TA.StateCode = B.StateCode
where TA.Stores is null
order by DA.Stores
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FiUyQ4hi)